# Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Tags: visual-c++

When I try building just a simple program into VS2010, compiling succeeds yet when I try to build the solution it gives me this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt after installing VS2012 release preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c)

Comment: same as this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c

Answer (score 69):

I had this issue and I solved it with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10890428/359170)

disable incremental linking, by going to

```
    Project Properties 
       -> Configuration Properties 
           -> Linker (General) 
              -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"
```

Comment: by far the best answer is my opinion

Comment: excellent, this fixed it for me, and didn't even require me to have to go redownload VS2012 :)

Comment: this solved my problem but will it be ok to give even production builds with this incremental linking option disabled? Can it have any side-effects?

Answer (score 36):

This issue occurred after Visual Studio 2012 installation.
The issue resolved by replacing the cvtres.exe from VS2010 with  the one from VS2012.

Thank you to "social.msdn"!

Comment: solved problem for me too.  I have new systems with VS 2012.  but had to install VS 2010 for compatibility with our work.

Comment: Works with DLL projects too(didn't see an incremental linking option in project setting there.) The file can be found in "<Visual studio>/VC/bin/" for both versions.

Answer (score 36):

I had this issue after installing dotnetframework4.5.
Open path below:
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"* ( in 64 bits machine)
or 
*"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"* (in 32 bits machine)
In this path find file *cvtres.exe* and rename it to *cvtres1.exe* then compile your project again.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Sadly, the other solution which s installing VS2010 SP1 adds more problems than it solves as : 1- installer enters an infinite loop writing to a temporary HTML file till is larger than 1GB! 2- installer finishes but Vs2010 with SP1 crashes when opening x64 C++ solution!

Comment: This works for me. `Windows 7 64 Bit` and `VS 2010 Ultimate`.

Answer (score 9):

Had to install VS 2010 SP1 in order to get it to work again for myself.  Lame microsoft.

Comment: I did not need to do the incremental linking=NO. I just needed to install SP1. I believe this is a better result, that users apply the update.

Comment: Installing 2010 SP1 worked for me also. (The incremental link solution was not relevant to me because I was getting this error even though my projects already had incremental linking disabled.)

Comment: This worked for me too and even though I had already installed it but I was still having this error but I assume windows updates has overriding something so re-installing SP1 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have Visual Studio 2012 installed as well? If so, 2012 stomps your 2010 IDE, possibly because of compatibility issues with .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.0.

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vssetup/thread/d10adba0-e082-494a-bb16-2bfc039faa80

Comment: I keep running into this prob. What works on VS2010 does not on VS2012 express. Just taking out VS2012 brilliantly solves.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

This happened to me when I installed .NET 4.5. 
Uninstall of .NET 4.5 and install of .NET 4.0 helped me and error messages disappeared.

Comment: nice thanks, this fixed it for my VS 2010 as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/12272425/32453

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed VS2012 as well, the old cvtres file will no longer work.

> Try removing the file (I simply renamed):
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cvtres.exe

You can also debug using the /VERBOSE linker option in order to get more information regarding the linker error.  There you should see an error message that the invoke to cvtres fails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just caused because there was not enough space on the disk for `cvtres.exe` to write the files it had to.

The error was preceded by this line

```
CVTRES : fatal error CVT1106: cannot write to file
```