# error related to c++ compile file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

when i am trying to run following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 class Rectangle
 {
 public:
     int x,y;
     Rectangle(int a,int b)
     {
          x=a;
          y=b;
     }

      int area()
      {
           return x*y;

      }


 };


int main()
{

    Rectangle a(3,4);
    cout<<a.area()<<"  "<<endl;


     return 0;
}
```

i am getting this error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: project_class, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

please helped me to clarify reason of this error

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10890428/2619912

Comment: You need to install the VS2010 service pack 1.

Comment: Nothing in your source code should cause that problem. There's probably something wrong with your build environment. What happens when you try to build a trivial program like `int main() { }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2757355

[Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267158/failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt)

[Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval)

Comment: Why did you just paste comments links ?