# Target Eye Autoupdate: fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Tags: c++

I found [Target Eye's Unique AutoUpdate mechanism on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310530/Target-Eye-Revealed-part-1-Target-Eyes-Unique-Auto)  autoupdating script.

But I got this error when building for VS2010:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file
>   invalid or corrupt 1> 1>Build FAILED.

I tried [stackoverflow: Failure during conversion to COFF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257619/2851862), it gave me this error:

> 1>stdafx.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to
>   '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Did specifying `/INCREMENTAL:NO` allow the linker to produce an executable (in other words, is your problem solved)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, it still says: "1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt"

Comment: "Rename the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cvtres.exe, so that the newer cvtres.exe in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 will be chosen. " seems to work in VS2010, but not in VS2012. This was suggested here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d10adba0-e082-494a-bb16-2bfc039faa80/vs2012-rc-installation-breaks-vs2010-c-projects?forum=vssetup

Answer (score -1):

The obvious thing is to do a file search through all your RC files for VS_VERSION_INFO, you may have another one defined, or alternatively you may have the same .rc file included twice ...

That said, I've had vs2010 do some really wierd things to me before with resource and source files, and the only way to resolve it was to remove the file from the solution, and re-add it

Comment: Where is `VS_VERSION_INFO` mentioned in the question, revision history, or links, out of curiosity?  That doesn't seem obvious to me...