# Error building hadoop 2.6 on windows - corrupt or invalid inutils.vcxproj

Tags: windows, hadoop, build

I'm trying to build Hadoop 2.6 on windows and installed the prerequisite as mentioned on their website. I;m getting the following fatal error while building it and the process stops. Any suggestions. Hadoop 2.5.2 built fine without any issues.

Thank you!

```
s\winutils.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or
 corrupt [C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\mai
n\winutils\winutils.vcxproj]

    57 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.67
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [0.671s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [0.577s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SUCCESS [1.734s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies .......................... SUCCESS [0.124s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SUCCESS [1.498s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ....................... SUCCESS [1.734s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC ............................. SUCCESS [1.390s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................ SUCCESS [2.434s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ....................... SUCCESS [1.920s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................. FAILURE [13.970s]
................................
................................
................................
................................
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.253s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 23 16:19:50 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 82M/1045M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (com
pile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process ex
ited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove .NET Framework 4.5 and install .NET Framework 4. After that, try to rebuild with the following command :

```
mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still relevant to you but I found the answer. You need .NET Framework 4. I had to remove .NET Framework 4.5  and install 4. Once I did that, the error went away.

Someone in another question had answered it but it was not specific to hadoop.
[Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267158/failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt)