# Getting Error While Installing Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 7 32 bit Machine

Tags: maven, hadoop

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]      
[INFO] Total time: 52.048 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-11T01:42:55+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/247M
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed.

Comment: Please help me to find out the solution for this problem.

Comment: You probably need to scroll up to figure out what the very first error was

Comment: LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or c
orrupt [C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.v
cxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winu
tils\winutils.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winu
tils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winu
tils\winutils.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Comment: "C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (de
fault target) (1) ->
"C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.
metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj"
 (default target) (4) ->
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or
 corrupt [C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils
.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Comment: Time Elapsed 00:00:05.07
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [ 30.882 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 59.135 s

Comment: [INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-11T11:16:28+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (c
ompile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process
exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: This is the whole log file generated at the time of building

Comment: So if you have any solution then please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop on Windows Building/ Installation Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295963/hadoop-on-windows-building-installation-error)

Answer (score 0):

The error you pasted seems to be the same as this one: [Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267158/failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt)

I also ran into it, I had to fully uninstall .NET Framework 4.5, reboot then install .NET Framework 4.0. See also my answer here for solutions to other problems you may run into: [Hadoop on Windows Building/ Installation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295963/hadoop-on-windows-building-installation-error/31331173#31331173)

Answer (score 0):

Verify msbuild.exe is on your path