# Hadoop building through Maven in Windows keeps failing

Tags: windows, maven, hadoop

I intended to develop Hadoop in Windows setting so
I first began with installing as below.

- cygwin, cmake, maven, Protocol Buffer 2.5, Windows SDK v7.1

Then I set the variables as below.

- M2_HOME=D:\java\apache-maven-3.2.1
- Platform=Win32

I added `C:\cygwin\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;D:\java\protoc-2.5.0-win32;` to path

and entered Hadoop root and ran `- mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`
from Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt

> (omitted) 
>   [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common .............................FAILURE [ 32.778 s]
>   (omitted)
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec
>   (complie-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution
>   faild. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>   (omitted)

complete logs url : http://pastebin.com/WAYezZmv

Such error as above keeps occurring which results in continuous failure in building.
If anyone could help find the solution to the problem, your insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!!

Comment: Please share complete logs using [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or others..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WAYezZmv <- complete logs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem in Hadoop. But i found the root cause, so that you can solve the problem yourself.

As checked your logs, the problem is because of Windows SDK v7.1 with .Net Framework 4.5

**Exception**

```
"D:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target\bin\libwinutils.lib" libwinutils.lib(libwinutils.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
Generating code
Finished generating code
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [D:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj]
"D:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj" 프로젝트를 빌드했습니다(기본 대상). - 실패
"D:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" 프로젝트를 빌드했습니다(기본 대상). - 실패
"D:\hdc\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" 프로젝트를 빌드했습니다(기본 대상). - 실패
```

Actual exception is

`fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt`

you can google it to find the solution. As I searched, pasted some links for this problem below

[LNK1123 Error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2757355) 
[LNK1123](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dz62kfh.aspx)

[Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval)
[Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267158/failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt)