# Link error using Visual Studio 2010 command prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, openssl, linker-errors

When building Openssl source code using Visual Studio x64 Win64 command prompt(2010) getting error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\amd64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x463' Stop.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12267158), [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10888391), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval)