# Visual Studio 2015 - Error 1123:

Tags: visual-studio

I have encountered a bizarre situation in which.....

a Win32 project (originally compiled/run using Visual Studio 2010) has been successfully carried over/updated and successfully compiled under Visual Studio 2015 on the same computer (mentioned just in case that is somehow relevant).

I now need to continue development of the project on a different computer. So I copy the ENTIRE contents of the project folder to an identically named folder on the new computer, with VS 2015 installed. The only difference being that the project folder is now on the D: drive rather than C: as in the original computer.

When I try to compile the program I get:-
fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

I experienced this error in the past with Visual Studio 2010 and fixed the problem as advised in previous articles such as:
[Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267158/failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt)

In this case however the puzzle is that, as mentioned above, the project has already successfully compiled on the computer it was copied from AND the new computer appears to have a correct and up to date VS2015 installation (e.g. the issue cannot be due to incorrect version of the CVTRES.EXE file - as was case when the same error was encountered in the past with Visual Studio 2010)

As far as I can tell the configuration settings for both VS2015 installations, on both computers are the same. The only difference as far as I can tell being that on the new computer the project now resides in a different drive/path - although the project folder is indentically named.

Can this really be the source of the problem?

Comment: Try adding the `/verbose` option to the linker command line (or project settings) and see if any helpful information is produced.

Comment: The problem has now been, apparently, solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has now been, apparently, solved.  I tried the /verbose option but that did not reveal any information or insight of any use.

The computer on which the project had been transferred to had Visual Studio 2010 WITHOUT service pack 1 installed. As an entirely separate exercise I proceeded to install service pack 1 (from a previously saved/archived ISO file).  It failed to install.  I then uninstalled VS 2010 from the computer.

I then tried again to compile my project using VS2015 - and again it failed, giving the error 1123.

I then performed a FULL re-installation of VS2010. I followed this with an another attempt to install the service pack 1 - which then succeeded.

After all this I then attempted to compile my project in VS2015 - and it succeeded!  The connection with the VS2010 may be completely coincidental?  But I mention this here for the record in case anyone else encounters a similar circumstance.

The puzzle is how, if at all, can the state of the VS2010 installation influence the ability to compile the project in VS2015.  The concern, more importantly, is that my continued ability to work on/compile the project using VS2015 will be dependent on the computer keeping VS2010 w/SP1 installed?!