# Microsoft Visual C 2010 Express: failure during conversion to COFF: file

Tags: coff

I get the following error, when I would like to make a Build solution.

> LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file
>   invalid or corrupt

Comment: Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c) Q&A, it provides the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS 2010 C++ but have had this error. I trawled the web looking for fixes and what finally did it (which I should have done much earlier was update to VS 2010 C++ SP1. Hopefully this is applicable to you and helps.