# VS 2010 Project out of date constantly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm new to this site so forgive me if I'm asking this in the wrong place.

I have VS 2010 which I use for my Programming class. Right now I've having a problem where I've written a simple "Hello World" program and when I try to run it, it says "Project out of date. "

"World- Debug Win32"

It then asks me to run it and if I choose "Yes" I get this message:

```
"1>------ Build started: Project: World, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 10/12/2012 2:50:17 PM.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "C:\Users\x Keyaki x\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects    \World    \Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\World.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  World.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:05.02
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

I'm still new to VS 2010 so I don't know everything about it, but I do know that if I make the same program on VS 2010 at my school, I know it will work fine. But if I try it at home, I get this message even though I would do the exact same process to make the program if I was school at home.

When I make the project and I always choose "Win32 Console Solution" with an "Empty Project". Again I do the same thing at school and everything works fine but when I do it at home on my own computer I get the above error messages.

Like I said, I'm still new to VS 2010 so I can't recall if I have any files of a "future date" or anything like that.

So, is there anyway to help me?

Comment: Have you installed VS2012 on your home computer?

Comment: I have once, but I uninstalled it. The thing is, when I had VS 2012, the same problem would occur.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the answer in this post will solve your problem; [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c)

It sounds like that error has been a common problem for VS 2010 users who have installed VS 2012.

Comment: I've tried everything in the link you've given me and still nothing worked.

Comment: Do you have service pack 1 installed? If not follow this link and install it. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Comment: Yea, I have SP1. But unfortunately, the problem still exists.