# Reading text files in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt after installing VS2012 release preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c)

I am trying to read a text file in c++ visual studio 2010 through a windows32 console app.  When using the fstream to try to read the text file I get the lnk 1123 error which says the conversion to COFF failed and that the file is either invalid or corrupt.  I know the file is just a simple text file with a list of numbers.  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Should we guess at what your code is doing?

Comment: can you show as some code and the exact error?

Comment: that has nothing do with the content of text file. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c

Comment: yes, install service pack 1 to your visual studio and the problem goes away

Answer (score 0):

`COFF`(Common Object File Format) is format of object files that generated by visual studio, and file that you try to open will be opened at runtime after you successfully create your output and run it, so it has nothing to do with linker and error. Try to rebuild your program, maybe some of your object files are invalid!