# Link error LNK1123 when using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, express

Every time I try to build and debug the simple Hello World Code I get an error stating the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: helloworld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And im using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main() {
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}
```

and i think its whenever i use `Main()`, they tell me not to use it or something. help!!!

Comment: Do you have any other versions of Visual Studio installed?  Have you tried repairing your VC++ 2010 Express install?

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c

Answer (score 0):

Try making it `int main()` and be sure to put `return(0);` at the end of the `main()` block.