# Qt Creator error: LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

When i tried to debug project on **QT 5.0 Creator** (MSVC2010(x86)compiler 10.0) i have this error:

**LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt**

I googled and i saw some solutions but only for **Visual Studio 2012**, i need solution of this problem for **QT Creator**.

Thank you.

*Before this problem i had problem with MSVC(x86)compiler 11.0, and i was installed MSVC2010(x86)compiler 10.0 and now i have this error.*

Comment: This usually happens when you upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c The answer from CaterHatterPillar worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sometimes i ask myself, why i installed vs2012.
Thank you, now works fine.

Comment: Exactly like what @VaibhavDesai said.  [This particular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29010876/999943) from that post worked for me.  Has to do with .NET 4.5 v .NET 4.0 and fixing the cvtres.exe.

Answer (score 13):

Set 
`QMAKE_LFLAGS += /INCREMENTAL:NO` in the file `.pro`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `QMAKE_LFLAGS += /INCREMENTAL:NO`, I "cleaned" and also removed the output directory to force a fresh recompile. Then the tutorial application built.

Comment: This Cleaning part was a must for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was solved by marking in Build -> "Open build and run kit selector" the MSVC2012 64bit version, instead of the 32 bit. Hope it helps!