# Error in visual studio 2012 (They were build errer)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm new at Visual studio 2010

When I hit "start debugging(F5)" obviously it says: "would you like to build it?"

then I push yes button and it is says:"There were build error. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

then I hit yes button and it says: "Unable to start program c:\users\My computer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tutorial1\Debug\tutorial.exe"

here is the Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: tutorial1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\tutorial1.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.13
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the build error? It's impossible to help without some kind of debug info.

Comment: Also be careful running the last successful build as it may not hit breakpoints that you set on the code you see in VS2010 because you are executing a previous build.

Comment: @Mohammad Kh: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @jacob aloysious, I rebuild it and this error happen.                                                                                        LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Comment: @tjameson: I added the output

Comment: This shows how to fix that LINK error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Answer:

> then I hit yes button and it says: "Unable to start program
>   c:\users\My computer\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\tutorial1\Debug\tutorial.exe"

This is the case where Visual Studio would try to launch the output of the previous build.

Visual Studio would try to launch the output of the StartUp project from the current Configuration (Debug/Release) output folder.

In your case "*c:\users\My computer\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tutorial1\Debug\tutorial.exe"* that was built during the last build operation would have been deleted.

The deletion could have happened as part of Clean operation. 
*Note*: Rebuild would run Clean and Build.

```
Based on the error posted:
```

[Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-c)