# CMake generator for Visual Studio in msys2?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015, msys2

I'm running `cmake` in `msys2`, but it doesn't seem to find Visual Studio 2015 (missing generator option). I am launching the `msys2` prompt from within Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, so I have `cl.exe`, `link.exe` etc in the path.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913804/cmake-not-finding-visual-studios-2012-in-generators-list) seems to be asking the same thing (however for `Cygwin` not `msys2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talked to the msys2 devs on IRC, turns out I needed to install package `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` instead of `cmake`. Using that fixed the problem.

Comment: Another option is to supply `-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/mingw64` and keep using /usr/bin/cmake .