# Failed to run custom build command for cryptominisat on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, cygwin, msys2

I am trying and failing to compile this [Rust code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125961/9206) in Windows. I have copied it below for completeness.  When I do `cargo build` I get:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling cryptominisat v5.0.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `cryptominisat v5.0.1`
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\foo\Downloads\rust\target\debug\build\cryptominisat-9c79fbb9e62f2dba\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\foo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\cryptominisat-5.0.1\\cryptominisat" "-G" "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\foo\\Downloads\\rust\\target\\debug\\build\\cryptominisat-d635308a8cbd254c\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

--- stderr
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64

Generators
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  KDevelop3                    = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
  KDevelop3 - Unix Makefiles   = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
```

My computer is running Windows 7 with Cygwin and I have gcc/g++ and cmake  installed from Cygwin. I would be happy trying any other method that works in Windows.

#### `src/main.rs`

```
extern crate cryptominisat;
extern crate itertools;

use std::iter::once;
use cryptominisat::{Lbool, Lit, Solver};
use itertools::Itertools;

fn make_solver(n: usize) -> (Solver, Vec<Lit>) {
    let mut solver = Solver::new();
    let s: Vec<Lit> = (1..n).map(|_| solver.new_var()).collect();
    let d: Vec<Vec<Lit>> = (1..n - 1)
        .map(|k| {
                 (0..n - k)
                     .map(|i| (if i == 0 { s[k - 1] } else { solver.new_var() }))
                     .collect()
             })
        .collect();
    let a: Vec<Lit> = (1..n - 1).map(|_| solver.new_var()).collect();
    for k in 1..n - 1 {
        for i in 1..n - k {
            solver.add_xor_literal_clause(&[s[i - 1], s[k + i - 1], d[k - 1][i]], true);
        }
        for t in (0..n - k).combinations(2) {
            solver.add_clause(&t.iter()
                                   .map(|&i| d[k - 1][i])
                                   .chain(once(!a[k - 1]))
                                   .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                                   [..]);
        }
        for t in (0..n - k).combinations(n - k - 1) {
            solver.add_clause(&t.iter()
                                   .map(|&i| !d[k - 1][i])
                                   .chain(once(a[k - 1]))
                                   .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                                   [..]);
        }
    }
    (solver, a)
}

fn search(n: usize,
          solver: &mut Solver,
          a: &Vec<Lit>,
          assumptions: &mut Vec<Lit>,
          k: usize)
          -> usize {
    match solver.solve_with_assumptions(assumptions) {
        Lbool::True => search_sat(n, solver, a, assumptions, k),
        Lbool::False => 0,
        Lbool::Undef => panic!(),
    }
}

fn search_sat(n: usize,
              solver: &mut Solver,
              a: &Vec<Lit>,
              assumptions: &mut Vec<Lit>,
              k: usize)
              -> usize {
    if k >= n - 1 {
        1
    } else {
        let s = solver.is_true(a[k - 1]);
        assumptions.push(if s { a[k - 1] } else { !a[k - 1] });
        let c = search_sat(n, solver, a, assumptions, k + 1);
        assumptions.pop();
        assumptions.push(if s { !a[k - 1] } else { a[k - 1] });
        let c1 = search(n, solver, a, assumptions, k + 1);
        assumptions.pop();
        c + c1
    }
}

fn f(n: usize) -> usize {
    let (mut solver, proj) = make_solver(n);
    search(n, &mut solver, &proj, &mut vec![], 1)
}

fn main() {
    for n in 1.. {
        println!("{}: {}", n, f(n));
    }
}
```

#### `Cargo.toml`

```toml
[package]
name = "correlations-cms"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Anders Kaseorg <andersk@mit.edu>"]

[dependencies]
cryptominisat = "5.0.1"
itertools = "0.6.0"
```

---

I tried switching toolchain with  `rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`.   Now I get this error:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling either v1.1.0
   Compiling gcc v0.3.50
   Compiling libc v0.2.23
   Compiling itertools v0.6.0
   Compiling cmake v0.1.24
   Compiling cryptominisat v5.0.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `cryptominisat v5.0.1`
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\foo\Downloads\rust\target\debug\bu                                  ild\cryptominisat-1b603d882d3d5aef\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\foo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db                                  9ec823\\cryptominisat-5.0.1\\cryptominisat" "-G" "MSYS Makefiles" "-DCMAKE_INSTA                                  LL_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\foo\\Downloads\\rust\\target\\debug\\build\\cryptominisat                                  -3d06123643d625eb\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -m                                  64" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -m64" "-DCMAKE_BUILD                                  _TYPE=Debug"

--- stderr
CMake Error: Could not create named generator MSYS Makefiles
```

---

I have now tried switching to using [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) . Sadly this also fails, this time with:

```
/c/Users/foo/Downloads/rust
$ cargo build
   Compiling cryptominisat v5.0.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `cryptominisat v5.0.1`
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\foo\Downloads\rust\target\debug\build\cryptominisat-a2f1d448eae9af61\build-script-build` (exit code: 3221225477)
--- stdout
running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\foo\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\cryptominisat-5.0.1\\cryptominisat" "-G" "MSYS Makefiles" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\foo\\Downloads\\rust\\target\\debug\\build\\cryptominisat-44b3c950a6288408\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -m64" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -m64" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"
-- Doing a Debug build
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

--- stderr
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_AR was not found, please set to archive program.
thread 'main' panicked at '
command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\foo\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.24\src\lib.rs:593
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
```

Comment: you must install Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 because `cryptominisat` need it, there is a free version.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913804/155423 — Tl;DR - Cygwin's `cmake` doesn't know how to create the Visual Studio files. Use the native Windows cmake instead. Probably worth reporting to the cryptominisat maintainers so they can update the documentation.

Comment: @Shepmaster I just tried that. How would I get the windows cmake into the cygwin path?   It still wants to use the cygwin cmake,

Comment: The same way you'd edit the Cygwin path for any other program. I'm not a Windows / Cygwin user, so I'd just be doing the same internet searches you can do.

Comment: Which Rust toolchain do you have installed? That targeting the MSVC ABI, or that targeting the GNU ABI?

Comment: @ildjarn I literally just run `cargo build` in cygwin. The only c/c++ compiler I have is gcc/g++.  I am a newbie to rust as you may tell.

Comment: @Shepmaster I just added the windows version  of cmake to PATH and now I get https://bpaste.net/show/793800778981

Comment: *'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command*. Looks like that is missing.

Comment: @Shepmaster Any idea what xxd is? Google gives me nothing for it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I opened an incognito window, went to Google, typed in "xxd" and 8 of the 10 results were all relevant. https://wiki.christophchamp.com/index.php?title=Xxd

Comment: @Shepmaster (I had googled the whole error message.) xxd installed. Now I get `c:\program files\haskell platform\8.0.2-a\mingw\include\zconf.h(452): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\foo\Downloads\rust\target\debug\build\cryptominisat-d635308a8cbd254c\out\build\cmsat5-src\libcryptominisat5.vcxproj]`

Comment: @eleanora : What is the output of `rustup toolchain list`? Does it end in `-gnu` or `-msvc`? If the latter, that's your problem; installing the GNU toolchain instead should cause CMake to get invoked with `-G MSYS Makefiles` instead of `-G Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64`.

Comment: @ildjarn `rustup toolchain list
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)`. How do I install the gnu toolchain instead?

Comment: @eleanora : No offense, but I'm quite sure the rustup docs cover that in detail... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn ok... I got that to work. Now I get  https://bpaste.net/show/56d870c3dba2 . Do I have to have msys instead of the gcc that comes with cygwin? Is there some way to get it to use -GUnix Makefiles  ?

Comment: @eleanora : "*Do I have to have msys instead of the gcc that comes with cygwin?*" For Rust in general, I'm not sure (I use the MSVC ABI on Windows), but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to work with Cygwin. But for this specific library, I think so, since it uses [cmake-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/cmake-rs) to invoke CMake, and cmake-rs [exclusively passes `MSYS Makefiles` when targeting windows-gnu from Windows](https://github.com/alexcrichton/cmake-rs/blob/b78c02db126d2cafbb457cb768d44d30dd0bfba4/src/lib.rs#L282). :-/

Comment: @ildjarn ah... I did manage to compile the cryptominisat separately using `cmake -GUnix Makefiles` so in principle it should be possible.

Comment: @eleanora : This appears to be a deficiency in cmake-rs – it seems to me that it could check for a `CYGWIN` environment variable and pass `-G Unix Makefiles` if it's present. You may want to open an issue on GH. (Or, it's possible that `host` isn't supposed to == `windows` when building under cygwin, in which case it's an environmental issue on your computer. I don't use cygwin, though, so I'm not sure, sorry.)

Comment: @ildjarn sadly it still fails in msys2 . I get https://bpaste.net/show/211f58910cd7