# Touching "Debug\opencvhaifa.unsuccessfulbuild".LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Tags: opencv

I am doing my project entraint end of study I try to implement this code in visual studio 2010 based on opencv 2.4.7 ais several times while I trouse same mistake I made ​​all the config...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval)