# EVENT LOGGING - Reporting an Event is not working

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

I want to implement the event logging as specified in the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363680(v=vs.85).aspx

I can successfully create a provider.rc, provider.h and provider.res as it is.

But when I try create the    *link -dll -noentry provider.res*    it gives me the following error

> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> LINK : warning LNK4068: /MACHINE not specified; defaulting to X86
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

I even tried the command below

*link /MACHINE:X64 -dll -noentry provider.res*

Still gave this error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

If this is of any use I used Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit OS.

**Edit: I have also tried the following method provided in the link.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0.aspx

It uses .rc file i have previously generated using mc command.

specified both NO INCREMENTAL and NO ENTRY option as specified.

Still not working. Gives the following error

> Build started 3/5/2014 11:50:16 AM.
>   InitializeBuildStatus:
>   Touching "Debug\evtlog.unsuccessfulbuild".
>   ClCompile:
>   All outputs are up-to-date.
>   All outputs are up-to-date.
>   ResourceCompile:
>   All outputs are up-to-date.
>
> evtlog.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I tried the example from the link you provided and while I saw the same warning about /MACHINE, the application compiled and linked and ran in debug mode.  I checked the application event log and could see my events.  I used Visual Studio 2005 on Windows XP.  The application was a Windows console application.  I did have to make changes to the Properties of the .mc file to add the commands for mc, rc, and link.  I added windows.h and the generated .h file from the mc command to the main source file.   see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825934(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also see if this may be your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2010 command prompt then I used using the Visual 2010 to create a new windows console application but I dont get to see the MESSAGE COMPILER in Configuration properties. 

I even tried this command **link /INCREMENTAL:NO /MACHINE:X64 -dll -noentry provider.res** it didnt work

Comment: I did the following.  created new windows console project in 2005.  copied and pasted the source code into same file as the main. added new a .mc file.  copied and pasted the mc source into the .mc file. opened Properties on the .mc file, added custom build step for mc, rc, and link using $(InputName) macro. added to stdafx.h include files for Windows.h, stdio.h.  put include for .h file generated by mc into the main below include of stdafx.h.  The difference may be I am on Windows XP 32 bit with visual studio 2005.  32 bit versus 64 bit.  It was simpler than I thought.

Comment: I am new to this I don't know how to add custom build step for VS2010.

Comment: Where do i add the macro you suggested.
http://i.imgur.com/d8yAE2h.png

Comment: To add a custom build step for a particular file you can select the file then do a right mouse click and then select the Properties menu item from the displayed menu.  for a .mc file about the only thing you can do is to add a custom build step.  you can then modify the Command Line to enter a series of commands. when you bring up the Command Line dialog that lets you enter a series of command lines there should be a button that says Macros>> that will allow you to insert macros that act like variables which will be replaced by actual values when the command line is executed.