# LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am building a c++ project (using point cloud library(PCL)) with CMake GUI & while configuring, I am getting the above error. This problem was posted in this forum before, but the problem arose after installing VS2012 version. But I have only VS2010 version in my machine.

Previously I had run successfully using CMake, but I guess somehow any file has been corrupted (may be after windows update?). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We encountered this problem also after installing a new version of the .NET Framework - 4.5 if I remember well. We solved it by installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 which made the problem disappear.

See 
[LNK1123 error when bulding VC++ 2010 project after installing Visual Studio 2012 or .NET Framework 4.5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2757355).

See also [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10890428/1945549) on stackoverflow.