# Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: failure while building the project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-vista

I have visual studio C++ 6.0 and visual studio C++ 2010 express installed in my PC. My friend is able to compile the same project in his PC with visual studio 2010 express.But my PC throws and error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF

I do not want to uninstall visual studio C++ 6.0. I have to keep that for other projects. I can uninstall/install Visual studio C++ 2010 express.

Please help me to solve this compatibility issue.
thank you.
[image]

```
UPDATE [SOLUTION] :
```

I solved issue by changing .NET framework.

I checked that my PC had .NET framework 4.5 installed so I uninstalled it and installed .NET framework 4. And now I can successfully compile my project in visual studio C++ 2010 express.

> I do not even need to set "Enable Incremental Linking" to "No
>   (/INCREMENTAL:NO)" without that also it is working.

Thank you all.

Comment: I see no evidence that VS6 is the problem. Step 1 for you is to isolate the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you.But what can I do to find the cause ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval)

Comment: All you had to do was what I just did and type the error message into a search engine. There are hundreds of hits. I've found a dupe question. There are many.

Comment: Ya David, I also found so many references in Google but none of them helped me and so am I here. Unfortunately, setting "Enable Incremental Linking" to "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)" does not work in my case.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that this a dupe

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by changing .NET framework.

I checked that my PC had .NET framework 4.5 installed so I uninstalled it and installed .NET framework 4. And now I can successfully compile my project in visual studio C++ 2010 express.

> I do not even need to set "Enable Incremental Linking" to "No
>   (/INCREMENTAL:NO)" without that also it is working.

Thank you all.