# How to solve failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++

I had developed visual c++ application in visual studio 2012 express.Now I am trying to run this application in visual studio 2010 express,I got error message " **failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt in Visual studio 2010**" .

How to solve the error in visual studio 2010 express.?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval). Also see [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2757355).

Comment: (1) Did you try an explicit rebuild?   (2) Can you paste the dump of a /VERBOSE link?