# fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Tags: opencv

i am beginner in using opencv.i have tried with simple a program of reading an image. the build was unsuccessful with following error:

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

i am using opencv 2.4.2 ,visual studio 2010.(windows 7 user). i checked my property sheet many times as per the instruction.please anyone help me in this. thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate, that question is not related to opencv

Answer (score 0):

I find out that I have the same problem. The problem is that my project setting is **debug** version, and the lib I include in the **linker-->input is release** version. After changing the project to **release** version, the problem disappear. After changing project to release version, you need to edit all the properties again.