# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when Im trying to run simple "Hello World" code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Everytime I try to run that simple code, my VS 2010 Ultimate crashes. And that includes all other programs. It worked before, without any problem. I have also re-installed it, but still the same. Im talking about C++

Error:

> Error 1   error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt   d:\Users\ADMIN\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\asasa\asasa\

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
cout << "Hello World";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
'Test.exe': Loaded 'D:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Visual Studio       2010\Projects\Test\Debug\Test.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file'Test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
 The program '[7164] Test.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

CODE 2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string s;
  cout << "Write a bunch of text: ";
  getline(cin, s);
  cout << "You typed: " << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I also get this related to VMWare. Could VMWare be the problem? https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2zBo690ggSdNXQ2RXp0ejZ1cGM/edit

Comment: What code, specifically?  What error message?

Comment: I added it to first post

Comment: [Known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval). TLDR: install the service pack, or turn off incremental linking.

Comment: `main()` should be declared as `int main()`, not `void main()`. I don't know that that will fix this code, it's just a nit-picking observation.

Comment: If I do that and also add return 0; to main program, it still the same

Comment: @AlessandraAmbrosio: `void main` is wrong, you must always use `int main`. The compiler should not even compile `void main` unless you invoke it with very strange flags. `return 0` is valid but optional. I would say just download the latest VC++ Express Edition.

Comment: You are trying to link a *directory* instead of a file.  Yeah, that can't work of course.  Do use a project template instead of trying to get all the compile and linker settings correct, pick the Win32 Console Application template when you create a new project.

Comment: WOW: sooo many comments about `void mian` on a *LINKING* problem in a question that's not about code portability and specic to an environment that accept `void main` in its own specifications?  Gee, at least read the question instead to profess your religion!

Comment: Your first error message indicates that the program did not successfully link, meaning that no .EXE file was built.  But your Output seems to indicate that the .EXE was not only built, but actually ran, and exited successfully.   Can you clarify if you successfully compiled, linked, and ran your program?  What result exactly did you get at each step?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an 'incremental link' problem.

set incremental linking to "NO" in the project's liker properties (project properties > configuration properties > Linker > Enable incremental linking: no)

Installing VS2010 SP1 will also resolve this.

[MSDN forum link 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/eb4a7699-0f3c-4701-9790-199787f1b359/vs-2010-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt?forum=vcgeneral)
[MSDN forum link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d10adba0-e082-494a-bb16-2bfc039faa80/vs2012-rc-installation-breaks-vs2010-c-projects?forum=vssetup)

Comment: Nope. Still shuting down

Comment: Updated the first post with OUTPUT

Comment: Your OUTPUT makes it appear that the text.exe program ran successfully and exited with code 0 (which indicates success).  Can you clarify if you ran the program?  If so, it seems that Visual Studio did not crash, and did successfully build your program.

Comment: Now it works sometimes for the basic code, but it doesnt work for Code Number 2. Updated

Comment: I also get this: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2zBo690ggSdNXQ2RXp0ejZ1cGM/edit