# VC++ appication error

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I am creating an application using VC++ but it I get an error when I try to build the application. I have been getting this error for quite some time what do I do. the error even comes when I start again and build it straight away, just after I create a new project what should I do. I am using VC++ 2010 express
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbspY.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval

Comment: What about including the error message *text* in the question?