# Unable to build C++ program in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010. When I build my C++ program I get this error

```
error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

I got a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval). So I do this:-

```
Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker (General) -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"
```

but it make no difference.
So, please tell me if there is any other solution.

Comment: Did you install SP1?

Comment: No, can you give me link.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Comment: PaulMcKenzie:-thanks