# CMake fails to configure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

Why isn't CMake working?

[image]

CMake build message:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/theWindows7User/Desktop/glfw-3.1.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



Run Build
Command:"C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe"
"cmTC_318a4.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0"

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.34209


[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34209]


Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 01-Jan-2016, Friday 6:35:52 AM.


Project
"C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_318a4.vcxproj"
on node 1 (default targets).


PrepareForBuild:


Creating directory "cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\".

Creating directory "C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".


InitializeBuildStatus:


Creating "cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\cmTC_318a4.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.


ClCompile:


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCCompiler.c

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCCompiler.c


testCCompiler.c


ManifestResourceCompile:


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe /nologo /fo"cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\cmTC_318a4.exe.embed.manifest.res" cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\cmTC_318a4_manifest.rc 


Link:


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_318a4.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\cmTC_318a4.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/Users/theWindows7User/Desktop/glfw-3.1.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_318a4.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/theWindows7User/Desktop/glfw-3.1.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_318a4.lib" /MACHINE:X86 cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\cmTC_318a4.exe.embed.manifest.res

cmTC_318a4.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj /machine:X86 /debug 


LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid
or corrupt
[C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_318a4.vcxproj]



Done Building Project
"C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_318a4.vcxproj"
(default targets) -- FAILED.



Build FAILED.




"C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_318a4.vcxproj"
(default target) (1) ->


(Link target) -> 


LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt [C:\Users\theWindows7User\Desktop\glfw-3.1.2\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_318a4.vcxproj]



0 Warning(s)

1 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.43






CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/theWindows7User/Desktop/glfw-3.1.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/theWindows7User/Desktop/glfw-3.1.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Do you have [SP1 installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval)?

Comment: CMake cannot compile anything with your compiler. Does it work for you manually? Maybe the installation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid
```

It's a classic Visual Studio issue. You *have* to install the service pack to fix it. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dz62kfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx