# Opencv 2.4.13 in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to install opencv 2.4.13 and in the include folder i've found only vc11 and vc12 indicating visual studio 11 and 12, and unfortunately I've visual studio 2010 so can I use any of them in linker property ?
and how can I solve that ?

Comment: No, you'll need to compile from source with VS2010, additionally openCV uses STL extensively so even if it didn't complain on linking it will likely crash when it tries to deallocate from a different heap due to incompatible dll versions

Comment: recompile OpenCV for Visual Studio 2010 (vc10)

Comment: How to recompile ?

Comment: compile using cmake

Comment: I've downloaded the appropriate version and it includes vc10 but now I am facing a new issue when testing my first project using opencv 
error "Error 1 error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
"

Comment: I've solved the new error by following this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888391/error-link-fatal-error-lnk1123-failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-inval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by re downloading earlier version of opencv or recompiling it myself in visual studio 2010 as advised by EdChum 
Hope this will help anyone has the same issue or inquiry