# Can CMake Create Solution for Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-express

Is CMake able to create solutions for Visual Studio Express 2010?

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio solution that will work with Visual Studio Express 2010 (for C++) but I keep running into issues. Whenever I try building the solution in Visual Studio I get the error `Invalid license data. Reinstall is required.`

In the output window I also see messages that state:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown.
-- The C++ compiler identification is unknown.
```

Comment: Can you open visual studio express at all? This error leads be to believe that it is not completely installed. (Have you fetched the free license code and activated it?)

Comment: @jkerian Yes, Visual Studio Express opens and is registered. Also, I can build other projects in there, just not ones generated by CMake.

Comment: @robhasacamera Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673275/how-do-i-fix-an-invalid-license-data-reinstall-is-required-error-in-visual-c)?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Visual Studio installed on your system? Are you opening the "cross tools command prompt" (that comes with visual studio) or the normal cmd?