# Setup projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I want to create a setup for project. I knew that my software development tools with Visual Studio Community 2015 are not enough without a tool for creating setup programs.

So, I'd tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects from this 
 [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) .

I create then, my SETUP PROJECT with help of [this  link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wzrns86C0BE), every thing is better until now , but when I go to execute the file.exe of my project that I was just created ,

there was an Error  **Invalid LICENCES Data.Reinstall is Required** .

[image]

Why in the Error it has been written **Visual Studio 2010 Shell ??** , I've installed Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects .

Please help me .Thanks

Comment: it is trying to running shell, you have to chosse VS manually

Comment: I didn't understand . How I choose VS manually ?

Comment: make it more simple, go to VS and from menu choose open project and redirected to your project and choose sln and use it

Comment: The problem is in my SETUP PROJECT not in my project .

Comment: Does this happen when you run your (newly created) setup? In this case it looks like it tries to install something actually? Have you told it to install something (check "pre-reqisites" you have selected?

Comment: Also google gives a lot of stuff on your message... Check out this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673275/how-do-i-fix-an-invalid-license-data-reinstall-is-required-error-in-visual-c